# Use cylindrical coordinates to find the volume of a solid.

Tags: calculus

> To Find: use cylindrical coordinates to find the volume of a solid that is enclosed between the surface $r^2+z^2=20$ and the surface $z=r^2$:

$$\iiint_R f(x,y,z)\,dv=\iiint_R f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)r\,dV$$

.R is part of the cylinder
$$x^2+y^2 \le R^2$$

> bounded by
>   $$x^2+y^2+z^2=20$$

$$z=x^2+y^2$$

$$z+z^2=20, z=4=x^2+y^2$$

> take part of the cylinder
>   $$\iiint_G\,dV$$

$$G=\left \{ (x,y,z):0 \le x^2+y^2 \le 4, x^2+y^2 \le z \le (20-x^2-y^2)^\frac{1}{2} \right \}$$

$$G=\left \{ (r,\theta,z): 0 \le r \le 2,0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, r^2 \le z \le (20-r^2)^\frac{1}{2} \right \}$$

$$Volume=\iiint_G \,dV=\int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r^2}^{({20-r^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}} r\,dz\,d\theta\,dr$$

> But where to from here?

Comment: The $dz$ integral is trivial, and the $d\theta$ integral is even more so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Just keep going.

$$Volume=\iiint_G \,dV=\int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r^2}^{({20-r^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}} r\,dz\,d\theta\,dr$$

$$\int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r^2}^{({20-r^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}} r\,dz\,d\theta\,dr=2\pi\int_0^2r(({20-r^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}-{r^2})dr=28.2$$